# How can I disable flip to one side in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I am using a pivot control in my wp7 application. I am displating some photos. I need to stop  right flip when the last photo is displaying. Also stop left flip when First photo is displaying. How can I disable flip in one direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to disable this behaviour with the default control.

You should be very wary of disabling this functionality. This is the behaviour that users familiar with other apps on the phone will expect the app to work/behave.

If you must have this functionality then you'll have to create a suitable control yourself.